# Yarn Cannot find module 'logform' winston in build

Tags: node.js, typescript, build, yarnpkg, winston

i'm trying to build with Yarn 2 one nodejs application with:

```
"build": "rimraf ./dist && tsc"
```

but i'm getting:

```
.yarn/cache/winston-transport-npm-4.4.0-e1b3134c1e-16050844d2.zip/node_modules/winston-transport/index.d.ts:9:26 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'logform' or its corresponding type declarations. 9 import * as logform from 'logform';
```

Even with this message the program still runs correctly. In dev no errors are logged in terminal.

typescript: 3.9.7

Yarn: 2.4.1

Node: 12.19.0

winston: 3.3.3

nodeLinker: pnp

Answer (score 1):

it seems that the Winston developers forgot to install the **logform** types in the **devDependencies** so all you need is to run the following command

```
yarn add @types/logform --dev
```

in your project and every thing will work as expected.